# Python string split using regex

Tags: python, regex, split

I tried to manage this myself but I coudn't...

I have text:

> {Łatwe|Proste} szukanie mieszkania {Sprawdź|Wypróbuj juz dziś},
>   znalezienie {wcale|w ogóle}

I want to get single words from sentence or whole expressions in `{}` to the list. So in list it will look like this:

- {Łatwe|Proste}
- szukanie
- mieszkania
- {Sprawdź|Wypróbuj juz dziś}
- znalezienie ...

I use `split()` method but it produces for example:

- {Sprawdź|Wypróbuj
- juz
- dziś}

But it should be one word.
I don't want to break expressions in `{}`.

**Any help?:)**

Comment: And what do you split with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 2.x solution:

```
>>> re.findall(r'{[^}]*}|\b\w+\b', u'{Łatwe|Proste} szukanie mieszkania {Sprawdź|Wypróbuj juz dziś}, znalezienie {wcale|w ogóle}', re.U)
[u'{\u0141atwe|Proste}', u'szukanie', u'mieszkania', u'{Sprawd\u017a|Wypr\xf3buj juz dzi\u015b}', u'znalezienie', u'{wcale|w og\xf3le}']
```

[`re.U`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.U) flag is necessary, since by default, `\b`, `\w`, and a few others (`\d`, `\s` and the negated counterparts) only matches ASCII characters.

Python 3.x solution:

```
re.findall(r'{[^}]*}|\b\w+\b', '{Łatwe|Proste} szukanie mieszkania {Sprawdź|Wypróbuj juz dziś}, znalezienie {wcale|w ogóle}')
```

In Python 3.x, `\b`, `\w`, `\d`, `\s` and their counterparts will perform matching on Unicode characters by default. `re.U` flag [still exists for backward compatibility](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.A), but it is redundant to specify.

Comment: Note that it will fail when the text outside `{}` contains diacritics. You need to indicate `re.U` flag.